# Suspend causes login screen corruption or system freeze

Tags: 14.04, login, suspend, fglrx, unity-greeter

At work, I often set my computer to "Suspend" rather than turning it off at the end of the day.

Often when I turn it back on in the morning, I find my login screen to look like this:

[image]

Note that, despite how it looks, I can still type in my password. Once I log in the problem is gone and everything works fine.

However, that's not all: sometimes when I turn my PC back on it after suspension it simply freezes up completely. Often I'll see one very specific notification icon (Jitsi, a Java SIP client) and the rest of the screen is completely black. To the point where I can't even switch to TTY or, for example, toggle my num lock.

Other days, though, it's completely fine and neither issue show up. I have not been able to find a pattern in this behavior.

I think these issues are connected with one root cause because they happen under the same conditions and both show strange graphic issues.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm on the fglrx-updates driver. My video card is a Sapphire R7 240 2GB.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: After a series of regular Ubuntu updates the pictured issue has  gone away. Unfortunately the freezing on a black screen still persists, and I have a new issue where the greeter works but doesn't have a usable password entry box or any icons on the top right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These issues continued to plague me for over 1,5 years. As it turns out, switching to the open source AMD video drivers (via the *Proprietary drivers* screen) fixed these issues and a variety of other issues such as rendering issues in Google Chrome for me.

The proprietary AMD drivers just don't seem to work properly.